# Mongoose - monitoring the life of the connection to db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use NPM mongoose package, for connect to MongoDB. And I need check the behavior - if the database is dropped, the connection should break.

But if you use the method

```
mongoose.connection.readyState
```

it returns me 1 (true)

How to make so that at falling base/connection is broken, I can track it in the app?

Answer (score 0):

You could register for specific event to be notified about disconnected database, and act accordingly:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('connected!');
});
db.once('disconnected', function() {
  console.log('disconnected!');
  // do your cleanup here
});
```

Here you can find full list of events fired by `connection`:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection